# RemoteViewsService not called

Tags: java, android, listview, widget, remoteview

I'm currently trying to add a `ListView` to my widget. Sadly, my `RemoteViewsService` does not get called.

Here's my widget refresh code :

```
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_today_layout);

Intent intent = new Intent(context, TodayWidgetService.class);
intent.putExtra("package", context.getPackageName());
intent.putExtra("items", items.toArray(new String[items.size()])); // items is just a List<String>

views.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.widget_today_content, intent);
manager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(ids, R.id.widget_today_content);
```

And the service code (in `TodayWidgetService`) :

```
@Override
public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(final Intent intent) {
    System.out.println("Called");
    return new TodayWidgetReceiver.WidgetFactory(intent.getStringExtra("package"), intent.getStringArrayExtra("items"));
}
```

As you can see, I print a `Called` message each time the service is executing. That's why I'm here : the message isn't in my console (therefore, the service is not called).

I added it in my `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
<application
...
    <service
        android:name="services.TodayWidgetService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS">
    </service>
</application>
```

Thanks for any help !

Comment: Actually it's seems like your code should work. Can you post all project on github? or make a sample project and post here? i will check

Comment: Hey, I actually solved my problem by taking everything [here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/AppWidget/LoremWidget/) and adapting it to my needs. The [source code](https://github.com/Skyost/UnicaenTimetable/) of my app is available though. I still can't figure why it does not worked :(

Comment: i will check ur source code later, and said why it doesn't work)

Answer (score 3):

Your onUpdate methods needs to be like this one:

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // update each of the app widgets with the remote adapter
    for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; ++i) {

        // Set up the intent that starts the StackViewService, which will
        // provide the views for this collection.
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, StackWidgetService.class);
        // Add the app widget ID to the intent extras.
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetIds[i]);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
        // Instantiate the RemoteViews object for the app widget layout.
        RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
        // Set up the RemoteViews object to use a RemoteViews adapter.
        // This adapter connects
        // to a RemoteViewsService  through the specified intent.
        // This is how you populate the data.
        rv.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.stack_view, intent);

        // The empty view is displayed when the collection has no items.
        // It should be in the same layout used to instantiate the RemoteViews
        // object above.
        rv.setEmptyView(R.id.stack_view, R.id.empty_view);

        //
        // Do additional processing specific to this app widget...
        //

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], rv);
    }
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
}
```

So check these things:

1. are you calling the `appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], rv);` in your refresh code?
2. You need to set appWidgetId and data to the Service intent, like so:

   intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetIds[i]);
   intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));

[Refer to the Android Developers docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/#implementing_collections)

Answer (score 3):

In my case ListView was places inside 2 FrameLayouts and I noticed such error messages in LogCat:

```
SetRemoteViewsAdapterIntent action can only be used for AppWidgets
```

Looks like parent of the parent of the collection must be AppWidgetHostView (you remote view are added to it on widget creation automatically) based on the code from setRemoteAdapter and SetRemoteViewsAdapterIntent:

```
 // Ensure that we are applying to an AppWidget root
 if (!(rootParent instanceof AppWidgetHostView)) {
     Log.e(LOG_TAG, "setRemoteAdapter can only be used for "
             + "AppWidgets (root id: " + viewId + ")");
     return;
  }
```

So I refactored the layout of my widget and made collection a direct child of the top parent of the widget views hierarchy and it works as expected after that.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by fixing the widget layout. Make sure you are using the right component for the `remote adapter`.

In my case, I used `RelativeLayout` which I fixed it by replacing it with `GridView`